# web browser isn't support anymore C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, console, webbrowser-control

[webBrowser bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9SrE.png)
**I want to join youtube with web browser , but I get this message,any idea?**

Comment: WebBrowser control? It's some ancient IE based thing.. Use a WebView2 or some other automatable modern(er) thing like GeckoFX

Comment: To use the WebBrowser control with moden web sites you will need to specify the IE version you want to use via registry settings. This post explains how to do this... [Web Browser Control & Specifying the IE Version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the browser used in visual studio is just IE (Internet Explorer) and since most websites doesn't support IE anymore, most popular sites like YouTube, Twitch, amazon, stack overflow ;) etc. use modern elements and the html/js/css in the website may not work with IE, so most websites either try to load the website or just show a "You need to update your browser version screen" (what you are experiencing right now)

EDIT: i found how to use Webview (not IE) so websites can work properly
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/

(NOTE: This is WebView1, Not The Newer WebView2, Please See [quaabaam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9541862/quaabaam) 's answer, here is the link for the answer he/she gave "
[Web Browser Control & Specifying the IE Version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)")

(NOTE 2: this link is from 2018 and its been 4 years now so im unsure if the code sample on the Microsoft blog post will work, this is due to .NET 6 and how it changes how you make methods and many more stuff)

Comment: Currently there is msedgewebview2 (in Windows 11)    download: [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), docs/intro: [Introduction to Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)